# Fastp can not open a file

Tags: fastq

I used `fastp` like this

```
> cat test | while read id
> do
>     name=`echo $id |awk '{print $1}'`
>     read1=`echo $id |awk '{print $2}'`
>     read2=`echo $id |awk '{print $3}'`
>     echo $name 
>     echo $read1 
>     echo $read2
>     fastp \
>         -i $read1 \
>         -o ./test_R1.fq \
>         -I $read2 \
>         -O ./test_R2.fq
> done
```

The test file is a txt file separate with \t

[image]

Then I got a error
[image]

But when I use `fastp` direct

```
fastp -i /home/imp008/private_hx_176/W034803N_HTW7JDSXX-L1_R1.fastq.gz -I /home/imp008/private_hx_176/W034803N_HTW7JDSXX-L1_R2.fastq.gz -o ./test_R1.fq -O ./test_R2.fq
```

It works!
So can you tell me why it can not open the R2 file?
Thanks!!

I used fastp but it return a error "can not open the file", but it works if I used fastp direct